# Android - how to set a text with two decimal places in a button

Tags: android

I need to set a button text with two decimal places. The value source is double that come like 1.0, 5.0, 10.0 or 100.0 and the string format below convert it to have two decimal places, So it is working.

```
            b = new Button(context);
            String stringdouble = String.format("%.2f", 1.0);

            b.setText(stringdouble);
```

However, even on debug mode the variable "stringdouble" be "1.00" or "5.00" or "10.00" or "100.00",
on the button they are displayed like "1.0", "5.0", "10.", "100".

Does anybody know why it happens??

thank you

Comment: let me guess, the button is too small with fixed width

Comment: Thanks @mihail. Actually that button is dynamically generated inside of a GridView and there the property android:columnWidth was fixed. Your tip gave me a import clue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using fixed width for your button. Set the button width to `wrap_content`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have to parameter your button to "wrap_content" in width.